# JS, WebGL: video displayed upside down

Tags: javascript, canvas, glsl, webgl, fragment-shader

Video is processed by WebGL shader that adds a blur filter and renders it on canvas. However, as a result, the video is displayed upside down. The demo is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/liubomyrB/jw20e1t7/60/). Whether it's upside down or not - depends on how many times the blur filter was applied. If the blur filter is applied an odd number of times, it will be upside down; if the number is even - then it will displayed normally.

To fix this issue I tried to add gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true); as it was described [here](https://jameshfisher.com/2020/10/22/why-is-my-webgl-texture-upside-down/). But it doesn't work for some reason.

My code that renders video with blur filter:

```
class WebGLRenderer {
    #ctx = null;
    #texWidthLoc = null;
    #texHeightLoc = null;
    #sigmaLoc = null;
    #fb = null;
    #fb2 = null;
    #tex = null;
    #texfb = null;
    #texfb2 = null;

    get ctx() {
        return this.#ctx;
    }
 
    static blurFilterShader = `
        precision mediump float;
        uniform sampler2D texture0;
        uniform sampler2D texture1;
        uniform float texWidth;
        uniform float texHeight;

        uniform float u_sigma;

        float CalcGauss( float x, float sigma )
        {
            return exp(-0.5*(x*x)/(sigma*sigma));
        }

        vec4 blur(vec2 texCoord, sampler2D texture, float sigma) {
            vec2 texC     = texCoord;
            vec4 texCol   = texture2D( texture, texC );

            vec4 gaussCol = vec4( texCol.rgb, 1.0 );
            vec2 steph     = vec2(1.0, 0.0) / texWidth;
            for ( int i = 1; i <= 32; ++ i )
            {
                float weight = CalcGauss( float(i) / 32.0, sigma * 0.5 );
                if ( weight < 1.0/255.0 )
                break;
                texCol    = texture2D( texture, texC + steph * float(i) );
                gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
                texCol    = texture2D( texture, texC - steph * float(i) );
                gaussCol += vec4( texCol.rgb * weight, weight );
            }
    
            gaussCol.rgb = clamp( gaussCol.rgb / gaussCol.w, 0.0, 1.0 );
            return vec4( gaussCol.rgb, 1.0 );
        }

        void main(void) {
            vec2 texCoord = vec2(gl_FragCoord.x/texWidth, 1.0 - (gl_FragCoord.y/texHeight));
            vec4 blur0 = blur(texCoord, texture0, u_sigma);
            gl_FragColor = blur0;
        }
        `;

    constructor(type, canvas) {
        this.canvas = canvas;
        this.lastWidth = 0;
        this.allSourceFilters = [];
        this.blurFilters = [];

        const gl = this.#ctx = canvas.getContext(type, {
            premultipliedAlpha: false,
        });
        gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);

        const vs = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(vs, 'attribute vec2 c; void main(void) { gl_Position=vec4(c, 0.0, 1.0); }');
        gl.compileShader(vs);

        const fs = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        gl.shaderSource(fs, WebGLRenderer.blurFilterShader);
        gl.compileShader(fs);
        if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fs, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
            console.error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fs));
        }

        const prog = gl.createProgram();
        gl.attachShader(prog, vs);
        gl.attachShader(prog, fs);
        gl.linkProgram(prog);
        gl.useProgram(prog);

        const vb = gl.createBuffer();
        gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, vb);
        gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([-1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        const coordLoc = gl.getAttribLocation(prog, 'c');
        gl.vertexAttribPointer(coordLoc, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        gl.enableVertexAttribArray(coordLoc);

        gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
        const tex = this.#tex = gl.createTexture();
        gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);

        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
        gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);


        //gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE);
        gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
        gl.disable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

        gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

        const texWidthLoc = this.#texWidthLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "texWidth");
        const texHeightLoc = this.#texHeightLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "texHeight");
        const sigmaLoc = this.#sigmaLoc = gl.getUniformLocation(prog, "u_sigma");

        const fb = this.#fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
        const texfb = this.#texfb = gl.createTexture();
        const fb2 = this.#fb2 = gl.createFramebuffer();
        const texfb2 = this.#texfb2 = gl.createTexture();

    }

    draw(frame) {
        this.canvas.width = frame.videoWidth;
        this.canvas.height = frame.videoHeight;
        let frameWidth = frame.videoWidth;
        let frameHeight = frame.videoHeight;
        
        const gl = this.#ctx;

        if (this.lastWidth != frameWidth) {

            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.#texfb);
            gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
            gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
                
            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, this.#fb);
            gl.framebufferTexture2D(
                gl.FRAMEBUFFER,
                gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,  // attach texture as COLOR_ATTACHMENT0
                gl.TEXTURE_2D,         // attach a 2D texture
                this.#texfb,                     // the texture to attach
                0);
        }
        

        let currentFrameBuffer = this.#fb;
        let currentTexture = this.#tex;
        for (let b in this.blurFilters) {
            let filter = this.blurFilters[b];
            //gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, currentFrameBuffer);
            //gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.#tex, 0);
            gl.viewport(0, 0, frameWidth, frameHeight);
            //gl.activeTexture(gl.TEXTURE0);
            gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, currentTexture);
            if (parseInt(b) == 0) {
                gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGB, gl.RGB, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, frame);
                
            }
            gl.uniform1f(this.#texWidthLoc, frameWidth);
            gl.uniform1f(this.#texHeightLoc, frameHeight);
            gl.uniform1f(this.#sigmaLoc, parseFloat(filter.sigma));
            if (this.blurFilters[parseInt(b) + 1]) {
                if(gl.getParameter(gl.FRAMEBUFFER_BINDING) == this.#fb) {
                    currentFrameBuffer = this.#fb2;
                    currentTexture = this.#texfb;
                } else {
                    currentFrameBuffer = this.#fb;
                    currentTexture = this.#tex;
                }
                
                gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, currentFrameBuffer);
                gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, currentTexture, 0);
                gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
            } else {
                gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
                gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
            }
        }
      
    }
    
    addBlueFilter() {
        let blurFilterData = {
            sigma: 0.08
        }
        this.blurFilters.push(blurFilterData);
        return blurFilterData;
    }
};
```

Why is this happening and how can it be fixed?

UPDATE:
I added gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true); in the wrong place. Moved it to the loop where blur filters are applied and added a condition that checks whether the number of filters is even or odd. This fixed problem, but only for cases when an image that is rendered by draw() is HTMLVideoElement. It doesn't work with ImageBitmap:

```
for (let b in this.blurFilters) {
        ...
        if (this.blurFilters[parseInt(b) + 1]) {
            ...
        } else {
            if(this.blurFilters.length % 2 == 0) {
                gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);
            }
            gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
            gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_FAN, 0, 4);
        }
    }
```

[Demo with HTMLVideoElement as an image source.](https://jsfiddle.net/liubomyrB/jw20e1t7/69/) Here workaround with UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL works fine.

[Demo with ImageBitmap as an image source.](https://jsfiddle.net/liubomyrB/jw20e1t7/76/) Here this workaround doesn't work.

So are there any other methods for flipping ImageBitmap vertically?

Comment: If that's your only problem, simply send your uv coordinates upside down, or subtract your y uv coordinate from 1 in your fragment shader.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ImageBitmap Options](https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/ImageBitmap_Options), you can flip image vertically, disregarding image orientation meta data (EXIF or other), if any.
Then flip the texture vertically using `gl.pixelStorei(gl.UNPACK_FLIP_Y_WEBGL, true);`.
e.g.:

```
const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(videoEl, {imageOrientation: "flipY"});
```